# Global selector with box-sizing

Tags: css, border-box

I read that some developers use the `box-sizing` in the global selector as common practice to the whole web project. This is a best practice or should be avoided? And about performance?

```
*{ 
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
   box-sizing:border-box; 
}
```

Comment: Depend on your layout ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it is fine to use.

Here is an optimized code snippet:

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Read here for more:

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

It's a best practice.

Read this:

http://learnlayout.com/box-sizing.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it a best practice,yes, but your layout would be distorted if you are also aiming for IE 7 and other older browsers. They don't support box-sizing.So, use it accordingly.